# Is there a convex polyhedron without triangulation?

Tags: polyhedra, solid-geometry, polytopes, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I'm thinking about such question.

> It there a convex polyhedron $P$ that is not a union of disjoint simplices which vertices are vertices of $P$?

It's not true for convex polygons. 
I belive that answer is "yes", but can't imagine a proper example.

P.S. The question arose when some of my students tried to prove Carathéodory's theorem in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Hint: First triangulate its boundary, then cone off this triangulation from one of the vertices.  You can then continue inductively and prove the same result in any dimension.

Comment: Is convexity needed? (It is not needed in the case of polygons)

Comment: @hagen-von-eitzen, it's another question :) and answer for it is intresting too.

Comment: @moishe-cohen, it's look like it works... but I remember that there was an intresting question near Carathéodory's theorem in $\mathbb{R}^3$...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Actually, not: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhardt_polyhedron